# Apache Poi, how to get the linked workbook?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I try to analyze excel files with links to other files and I like to know the file name and path. For that I'm using apache poi 3.14.

I figured it out for Ref3DPtg objects but for Ref3DPxg I don't know how to do it. I only get access to the cell address and the sheet name.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Code:

```
...
if(ptg instanceof Ref3DPxg){
    cellAddress = ptg.format2DRefAsString(); 
    sheetName = ptg.getSheetName();
    workbookName = ???;
} else if(ptg instanceof Ref3DPtg) {
    // by Ref3DPtg is no problem
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way that the XLSX file format stores external references, which isn't actually `=[Other.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` but actually `=[23]Sheet1!A1`, it's a two step process. First, [get the external workbook number from the Pxg](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Ref3DPxg.html#getExternalWorkbookNumber%28%29). Next, from [Workbook get](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getExternalLinksTable%28%29) the [ExternalLinks table](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ExternalLinksTable.html) for that workbook number, noting the off-by-one. (External Workbook 0 is actually the current workbook, so External Workbook 1 corresponds to External Link 0). Finally, fetch the [filename for that link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ExternalLinksTable.html#getLinkedFileName%28%29)

So, your code should be something like:

```
if(ptg instanceof Ref3DPxg){
   Ref3DPxg pxg = (Ref3DPxg)ptg;
   int extWB = pxg.getExternalWorkbookNumber();
   int extLink = extWB-1;
   ExternalLinksTable links = wb.getExternalLinksTable().get(extLink);
   String filename = links.getLinkedFileName();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get external links table for xls files and update the linked url